# 500 INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR while PayPal Cancel Subscription (.Net Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Implementing PayPal Subscriptions:

1. Subscriptions via PayPal Payment standard.
2. Cancel Subscriptions via PayPal API (Without SDK).

I am facing issues while cancelling the Subscription/Recurring Payment via PayPal API. I was able to get the AccessToken via the API. Below is my code for cancelling subscriptions:

```
string url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/" + mySubscriberId + "/cancel";
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + myPaypalAccessToken);
var request = ("note=" + myCancelNote);
byte[] req_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
webRequest.ContentLength = req_bytes.Length;

Stream strm = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
strm.Write(req_bytes, 0, req_bytes.Length);
strm.Close();

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
using (Stream respStr = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStr, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string jsonString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        reader.Close();
    }
 }
```

I get the following response everytime:

"name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
"message": "An internal service error occurred.",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
"debug_id": "c121fd139b91b"

Can someone assure me if i am on the right track & what might be the cause for the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct ID? Not sure is subscriber Id for you is your agreement id or not. The API says: Cancel agreement
POST
/v1/payments/billing-agreements/{agreement_id}/cancel
Cancels a billing agreement, by ID. In the JSON request body, include an agreement_state_descriptor object with an optional note that describes the reason for the cancellation and the agreement amount and currency.

Comment: @Mr00Anderson, {subscr_id} which is received by IPN, is the only value which is common across all subscription transactions. I hope {agreement_id} in the API Call also refers to the same.